# Can simple variable used in knockout view model for binding

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

Is it required to use only observable and observableArray in knockout view model?

Or we can use simple variable to bind data?

Comment: Please show an example of what you are trying to achieve with some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Not necessarily we need observables/observableArray for binding it to view

2.you can bind a plane data to view but you do something like this

> this.data={'firstName':'Stackoverflow'}

or

> data = {'firstName':'Stackoverflow'}

working sample `:` **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26270/)**

**PS:** Until unless if you are completely aware of what 2-way binding does you can go-ahead

Comment: Yes i am aware of to way binding but few places that is not required, so i don't want to use observables.